# Extending AuditedAttribute to substitute or mask audited values

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, audit-logging, data-masking, .net-attributes

I am using ABP version 3.8.2. I have enabled [ABP Audit Logging](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Audit-Logging) and it's working fine.

Is there any way to substitute or mask Audit Log value with a different value in order to hide sensitive information like Password, Credit Card details, etc.? Maybe by extending ABP's [Audited](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Audit-Logging#enable-disable-by-attributes) attribute.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: My use case is not to hide or disable auditing on sensitive values, my use case is to : 
1. Substitute with a different value
2. Mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can substitute or mask audited values in order to hide sensitive information.

1. Implement `MaskableAuditSerializer`:

   ```cs
   public class MaskableAuditSerializer : IAuditSerializer, ITransientDependency
   {
       private readonly IAuditingConfiguration _configuration;

       public MaskableJsonNetAuditSerializer(IAuditingConfiguration configuration)
       {
           _configuration = configuration;
       }

       public string Serialize(object obj)
       {
           var options = new JsonSerializerSettings
           {
               ContractResolver = new MaskableAuditingContractResolver(_configuration.IgnoredTypes)
           };

           return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, options);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement `MaskableAuditingContractResolver` by inheriting `AuditingContractResolver`:

   ```cs
   public class MaskableAuditingContractResolver : AuditingContractResolver
   {
       public MaskableAuditingContractResolver(List<Type> ignoredTypes)
           : base(ignoredTypes)
       {
       }

       protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
       {
           var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

           if (member.IsDefined(typeof(MaskedAuditedAttribute)))
           {
               property.ValueProvider = new MaskedValueProvider();
           }

           return property;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Implement `MaskedValueProvider`:

   ```cs
   public class MaskedValueProvider : IValueProvider
   {
       public object GetValue(object target)
       {
           return "***";
       }

       public void SetValue(object target, object value)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Implement `MaskedAuditedAttribute` by inheriting `AuditedAttribute`:

   ```cs
   public class MaskedAuditedAttribute : AuditedAttribute
   {
   }
   ```

## Usage

```cs
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [MaskedAudited]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```